# Two white blinking dots on HTML element in Chrome when using a box-shadow

Tags: css, google-chrome, vuejs2

I am developing my own component library for vuejs2 and I have chosen to use box-shadow instead of borders (for a little more flexibility, yes it isn´t the best I know, but looks and works better for my needs)

I mostly see this happening when I am not focusing the tab for about 1 minute.
The dots are white can appear on either side of the element, appear right before the border-radius curve, when zooming in the dots are still the same size on screen as with 100% zoom, interacting with the element "buries" them into the element, they will come back out after a few seconds.

Here are a few examples:
[image: Two dots on left side of a checkbox component]

[image: Two dots on the top side of a button component with a box-shadow outline]

[image: Two dots on the left side of an input component with a box-shadow outline]

This problem is only known in **Chrome Version 97.0.4692.99 (Official Build) (64-bit) Windows 11**, so far.
Tested with Firefox and Opera, all where fine.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list is the place to post this. This one, although reported on ChromeOS not Chrome, seems similar: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1020099&q=white%20dots&can=2

Comment: What is your actual question? Reads more like a bug report.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue on Chrome, albeit somewhat inconsistently. I assume OP is asking if there is a fix for this, so let me ask instead, is there a workaround for this?